# Getting count of cases of a variable from one table such that its entries are different in an another column of different table in SQLlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So here it is,

I've from customers table:

- customersid (unique for each customers)
- customers' city

from invoices table:

- billing city
- customers id

Now i've to find customers id whose billing city is different from city they live (customers_city). My code is this:

```
Select Customers.customerid, Customers.city, Invoices.Billingcity
From Customers Inner join
     Invoices
     ON customers.city <> invoices.billingcity
```

Now the problem is that count of unique customer_id (1,2,3,4) and number of mismatch cases in another column. But what I am getting is something like this:

(read it like this, after billing city, when the 1 (customer_id) repeats it indicates its a new entry).. I don't know how to format this column, sorry

```
CustomerId   | City                | BillingCity |
|          1 | São José dos Campos | Stuttgart   |
|          1 | São José dos Campos | Oslo        |
|          1 | São José dos Campos | Brussels    |
```

(Output limit exceeded, 10 of 23812 total rows shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on the customer id and then compare the cities:

```
Select c.customerid, c.city, i.Billingcity
From Customers c join
     Invoices i
     on c.customerid = i.customerid
where c.city <> i.billingcity;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon Linoff, I appreciate your response and editing my question as well.